# How to save this image as a variable?

Tags: php

I need to know how to save this line of code as a variable(if possible) so I can put it in a wrapper to display with the blog posts. If not possible, would there be any other way to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
<img src="imageView2.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"/>
```

Here is the wrapper:

```
$newtext3 = wordwrap($poets, 65, "\n", true);
```

Here is the $poets variable(the blog post)

```
$poets .= "<a class='demo shareSelector' <a class='eh3' style='' 
href='javascript:;' ><h2 class='eh4' href=''> Category:$category</h2><h1 
style='color:cyan; text-align:center; '>$title</h1><h3 >$date</h3><h2 
class='eh4'>$output</h2></a></a>
<hr>";
```

Here is the imageView2.php page:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db ($conn,'blog');
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

$sql = "SELECT imageType,imageData FROM posts WHERE id=" . $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on 
Retrieving Image BLOB<br/>" . mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-type: " . $row["imageType"]);
echo $row["imageData"];


}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: `wordwrap` on HTML doesn't make sense. `</a></a>` either.

Comment: Are you wanting to store the html after interpolating php variables into it? Or did you want to store the html + PHP code (to execute the php code later) ? Its unclear your question, as you didn't really provide a solid example of the raw content you wish to save, and what you want it to look like.

Comment: I want the image to be displayed when the $poets code is executed. I would just include(for example) an $image variable just after the $output variable that you see in $poets. Sorry If my question is unclear, because I am having trouble knowing what the best option actually is.

Comment: Would it help to store it like this: `<?php $image = '<img src="imageView2.php?id='.$row["id"].'"/>';?>` then use `<?php echo $image; ?>` where needed, or just `$image`? However the wordwrap will destroy any HTML. What reason are you using the wrapper?

Comment: ^ thank you, this is exactly what I needed